# Flutter webpage "go back" control

Tags: flutter, popup

I am currently making a web page using flutter.

I'm having trouble implementing navigating between pages using the go_router package.

The current development environment is as follows.

1. Flutter v3.7.11
2. iPhone12 & Safari

For example, assuming that the page stack consists of [A, B, C],

if a pop-up is displayed on page C,

clicking the browser's back button will take you to page B.

This is because popup type pages cannot create GoRoute objects.

Is there a way to close only the popup page by clicking the back button?